# Vue-Router: Going Back Sometimes Skips

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using vue-router and have noticed that `this.$router.go(-1);` sometimes skips and goes farther back in the URL history than it should. It may even be jumping directly to the `"/"` route.

According to the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html), it appears that I'm using it correctly.

**Context**

```
// routes.js
{ path: 'calls/:callKey/snapshot', name: 'Snapshot', component: Snapshot},

// Calls.vue
this.$router.push({
    name: 'Snapshot',
    params: { callKey: record.CallKey }
});

// Snapshot.vue
this.$router.go(-1);
```

- `vue: 2.3.2`
- `vue-router: 2.5.3`

Comment: Can you put something together that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: It's a pretty large app, so I can't easily reproduce it for testing purposes, but I've updated the description with some basic context. Hopefully it helps.